# I am facing an issue with the width of the Flutter dialog box in tablet view. The dialog box doesn't take the full width

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog

facing an issue with the width of the Flutter dialog box in tablet view. The dialog box doesn't take the full width.

I'm encountering a specific issue with the width of the Flutter dialog box in tablet view. Despite trying various approaches, the dialog box doesn't take the full width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to put this in your dialog

```
constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: double.infinity),
```

Comment: than please correct my answer or else vote it, it help me a lot